# Constructor Signature Constraints on Type Parameters

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

```
public static IEnumerable<TV> To<TU, TV>(this IEnumerable<TU> source) where TV : new(TU)
{
    return source.Select(x => new TV(TU));
}
```

The problem is that I can't give the new(TU) constraints.

- **Is there any solution to this problem?**

Comment: you can only specify default constructor ,constructor with parameters are not allowed in C#.

Comment: @Srinivas Yes, I noted that. But is there any why to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the easiest way is to explicitly give the formula from `TU` to `TV` at the calling place like option 1 here after. If you prefer to hide the details of the transformation behind the scene to have it work anywhere where you call the extension method to avoid repeating the formula, then an interface is appropriate since it can be used as a constraint for an extension method :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<U> uSequence = new List<U>();
        IEnumerable<V> vSequence1 = uSequence.To(u => new V(u)); //Option 1 : explicit transformation, needs neither any interface nor explicit types (type inference at work)
        IEnumerable<V> vSequence2 = uSequence.To<U, V>(); //Option 2 : implicit transformation internally supported from U to V by type V thanks to IBuildableFrom<TV, TU>, but you must precise To<U, V>() with the types
    }
}

public static class Extensions    {
    //Option 1
    public static IEnumerable<TV> To<TU, TV>(this IEnumerable<TU> source, Func<TU,TV> transform)
    {
        return source.Select(tu => transform(tu));
    }

    //Option 2
    public static IEnumerable<TV> To<TU, TV>(this IEnumerable<TU> source) where TV : IBuildableFrom<TV, TU>, new()
    {
        return source.Select(tu => new TV().BuildFrom(tu));
    }
}

public interface IBuildableFrom<TV, TU>
{
    TV BuildFrom(TU tu);
}

public class U { } //Cheesy concrete class playing the rôle of TU
public class V : IBuildableFrom<V, U> //Cheesy concrete class playing the rôle of TV
{
    public V BuildFrom(U u)
    {
        //Initialization of this' properties based on u's ones
        return this;
    }

    public V(U u) { }//Used by option 1
    public V() { } //Used by option 2
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've got two approaches for you:

Firstly using Activator.CreateInstance

```
public static IEnumerable<TV> To<TU, TV>(this IEnumerable<TU> source)
{ 
  return source.Select(m => (TV) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TV), m));
}
```

Secondly, you could use interfaces to define properties rather than use parameterized constructors:

```
public interface IRequiredMember
{}

public interface IHasNeccesaryMember
{
  IRequiredMember Member
  {
    get;
    set;
  }
}

public static IEnumerable<TV> To<TU, TV>(this IEnumerable<TU> source)
            where TV : IHasNeccesaryMember, new()
            where TU : IRequiredMember
 {
    return source.Select(m => new TV{ Member = m });
 }
```

The first method works but feels dirty and there is the risk of getting the constructor call wrong, particularly as the method is not constrained.

Therefore, I think the second method is a better solution.

Comment: How can I change Member to constructor of TV?

Comment: @Amir: you can't define constructors using interfaces - See ISerializable for example, so member specification is as close as you're going to get I think.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe pass in a Func which can create a TV from a TU:

```
public static IEnumerable<TV> To<TU, TV>(
    this IEnumerable<TU> source, 
    Func<TU, TV> builder)
    where TV : class
{
    return source.Select(x => builder(x));
}
```

and call with

```
tus.To(x => new TV(x));
```

Comment: +1 Compliantly different of what I was thinking, but very interesting approach.

Comment: @Amir yeah, I'm not sure about it myself, on one hand it moves the knowledge of how to create TV objects from the extension method to the caller, but on the other it's a bit more flexible in how the TV objects are created.

Comment: @Graham Clark: Your implementation could be shortened to "return source.Select(builder)". How is this different from using Enumerable.Select directly "tus.Select(x => new TV(x));"?

Comment: @Konstantin I also noted that problem. Then we are back where we started. This works as buildin Converter class.

Comment: @Konstantin with this one you don't need to use `new TV(x)`, you could use anything that creates a TV. It depends what you're trying to do. I think @Xhalent's solution is probably more applicable to this particular problem.

Comment: @Graham Clark again, it's the same as Enumerable.Select, so why wrapping it in the first place? This wrapper only adds unnecessary restriction for TV to be a class.